# How did Holland’s actions restore White London?

Tags: shades-of-magic

In *A Conjuring of Light* by V.E. Schwab, Holland (what one might call a bit of an antivillain), goes back to his home London after helping defeat the final antagonist. It is *strongly implied* that as he dies, magic returns to White London, arresting its steady decay:

> A gentle breeze blew through the barren grove, and Holland closed his
>   eyes and imagined he could almost hear the rustle of leaves, could
>   almost feel the feathery weight of them falling one by one onto his
>   skin. He didn’t open his eyes, didn’t want to lose the image. He just
>   let the leaves fall. Let the wind blow. Let the woods whisper,
>   shapeless sounds that threaded into words.
>
> ***The king is coming*, it seemed to say.**
>
> The tree was beginning to warm against his back, and Holland knew, in
>   a distant way, that he was never getting up.
>
> It ends, he thought—no fear, only relief, and sadness.
>
> He had tried. Had given everything he could. But he was so tired. The
>   rustle of leaves in his ears was getting louder, and he felt himself
>   sinking against the tree, into the embrace of something softer than
>   metal, darker than night.
>
> His heart slowed, winding down like a music box, a season at its end.
>   The last air left Holland’s lungs. **And then, at last, the world
>   breathed in.**
>
> <sub>*A Conjuring of Light*</sub>

This is clear from the constant references to a king who will save White London and restore it to balance.

This makes a lot of sense character-wise, and puts Holland’s tortured arc to rest quite nicely. How did this happen, though? Certainly it was not Holland’s Antari magic returning to White London, since by this point it was all gone, sacrificed to imprison Osaron. How did Holland’s death restore White London?

Comment: Ah, good to see that at least one person has read this! ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would seem that Holland's death did not "return" magic to London, per se. Rather, magic itself decided to return in response to Holland's sacrifice.

According to my correspondence with the author, V.E. Schwab, who was kind enough to answer my questions:

> **V.E. Schwab**: And yes, Holland’s death in White London triggers the return—or at least the beginning of the return--of magic to that world. He was the prophesied Someday King. **Magic originally withdrew from White London due to corruption and the hunger for power. Holland’s actions, his desire only to restore his world, signaled that it was time for magic to return.**

So magic seems to have consciously removed itself from White London and its world, due to the attitudes of the people there.

This fits with what was said in the first book:

> Here, magic was not seen as equal. It was seen as something to be
> conquered. Enslaved. Controlled. Black London had let magic in, let it
> take over, let it consume. In the wake of the city’s fall, White
> London had taken the opposite approach, seeking to bind power in any
> way they could. *Power in Balance* became *Power in Dominance*.
>
> **And when the people fought to control the magic, the magic resisted
> them.** Shrank away into itself, burrowed down into the earth and out of
> reach. The people clawed the surface of the world, digging up what
> little magic they could still grasp, but it was thin and only growing
> thinner, as were those fighting for it. The magic seemed determined to
> starve its captors out. And slowly, surely, it was succeeding.
>
> <sub>*A Darker Shade of Magic*</sub>

In other words, the magic didn't leave the world entirely, but rather withdrew in response to the attempts to control it. It's even implied that it was still on the planet, simply too far belowground for humans to access.

When someone was willing to go as far as Holland for the sake of the world itself, rather than for power, magic sensed a shift and changed its mind. Perhaps it didn't hurt that Holland was Antari, either, with a deeper connection to magic.

That magic can make such conscious decisions should come as no surprise: magic is basically an entity like Osarion, as evidenced by Osarion's ability to singlehandedly (though temporarily) rejuvenate White London.